# What Does Local file mean for KML?

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

The Documentation for Google Earth says I should be able to access files on my local drive, yet i cannot find an example and when I try to use the KML on my local drive it doesn't seem to be loading.  I see a lot of answers saying it can't be done, But why does the Documentation say otherwise?

**My Code**

```
var href = 'http://code.google.com/'
                     + 'D:/visual studio 12/Projects/myMap/myMap/myPoints.Kml';
```

*Example*

> **Network Links**
>
> A network link contains a  element with an  (a hypertext reference) that loads a file. The  can be a
>   local file specification or an absolute URL. Despite the name, a
>    does not necessarily load files from the network.   The
>    in a link specifies the location of any of the following: •An
>   image file used by icons in icon styles, ground overlays, and screen
>   overlays  •A model file used in the  element  •A KML or KMZ
>   file loaded by a Network Link
>
> The specified file can be either a local file or a file on a remote
>   server. In their simplest form, network links are a useful way to
>   split one large KML file into smaller, more manageable files on the
>   same computer.
>
> So far, all of our examples have required that the KML code be
>   delivered to Google Earth from the local machine. Network links give
>   you the power to serve content from a remote location and are commonly
>   used to distribute data to large numbers of users. In this way, if the
>   data needs to be amended, it has to be changed only at the source
>   location, and all users receive the updated data automatically.

I have done some changeing and testing and figured out the error has to be in my HTML file not in the KML file.  If I click on the HTML file I get the same results as I do running my program.

Am I correct in thinking that you run your HTML file and it should call the KML?  Or do I just call the KML to open GE?

This is my Sample HTML I am tring to make run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ge;
        google.load("earth", "1.x");

        function init() {
            google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
        };

        function initCB(instance) {
            ge = instance;
            ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
            var href = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61240296/myPoints.Kml';
            google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, kmlFinishedLoading);
        };

        function kmlFinishedLoading(obj) {
            kmlObject = obj;
            if (kmlObject) {
                if ('getFeatures' in kmlObject) {
                    kmlObject.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
                }
                ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
                if (kmlObject.getAbstractView()) {
                    ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
                }
            }
        };

        function showHideKml() {
            kmlObject.setVisibility(!kmlObject.getVisibility());
        };

        function failureCB(errorCode){};

        google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map3d" style="height: 320px; width: 679px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are simply mistaking the meaning of `local file specification`, it doesn't mean a local file on your machine - it means a relative path on the domain. See my answer for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking the meaning of `local file specification`. If you read the documentation it doesn't say anything about a file "on your computer" it actually says.

> The (sic) can be a local file specification or an absolute URL

What this means is that the file specification can be relative or absolute - local means local relative to the domain hosting the page, *not* local on your home computer!

In simple terms, imagine my site is located at (this would be your Sample HTML)

`http://www.somesite.com/`

I also have a kml file, that contains a Network link, located at

`http://www.somesite.com/kml/foo.kml`

and finally some images located at

`http://www.somesite.com/images/`

The code in the Sample HTML - can use *a local file specification or an absolute URL* to refer to the files.

i.e. it can use

**local** `google.earth.fetchKml(ge, '/kml/foo.kml', ...`

**absolute**: `google.earth.fetchKml(ge, 'http://www.somesite.com/kml/foo.kml', ...`

Also, the Network Link in `foo.kml` can also use *a local file specification or an absolute URL* to refer to the image files.

i.e.

**local** `<href>../images/pic.jpg</href>`

**absolute**: `<href>http://www.somesite.com/images/pic.jpg</href>`

Comment: I tried this out but I get a big X cross whenI load the local image on my Ubuntu - My code is like this - <Icon>
       <href>wm5midshr.GIF</href>
    </Icon>

Comment: @gansub I am not sure what you mean, the Google Earth plugin has been deprecated for years... Also - if you have an issue/problem you should ask your own question. There isn't nearly enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the `Documentation for Google Earth` but you have tagged the question Google Maps, Google Maps API v3.  Google Earth is an application that runs on your local machine and has access to your local hard drive, the other two are web based.

If you are using the Google Maps API v3, the native object that handles KML is [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer), that object requires the to be publicly available so Google's servers can retrieve it and render it for display on the map.

Comment: Sorry about that but they seem to be intermingled on the Google Forums.  It looked like there was a message saying that Google Earth had also moved here with the tags I used..

Comment: Try the [google-earth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-earth) tag if you are asking about Google Earth

Comment: I changed it before you posted.